# How to import PLActorKit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wanted to try out PLActorKit for iPhone: http://code.google.com/p/plactorkit/
but I still get the error, that classes from this framework can't be found.

I downloaded the the .dmg file and added the ActorKit.framework to my project. In the class I want to use the framework I wrote

```
#import <ActorKit/ActorKit.h>
```

in the .h file.

When I try to use classes from the ActorKit framework in my .m file I still get the error

*_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLActorKit*, referenced from: Objc-class-ref-to-PLActorKit in myClass.o
Symbol(s) not found

I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

where are the headers located? if they are in your classes directory then try using:

```
#import "ActorKit/ActorKit.h"
```

else you need to add the directory containing the headers to the headers search path. for whatever reason it can't currently find the headers, or the static framework/project isn't being built. you may have to set it up as a direct dependency.